# Arduino Mega 2560 as ISP for ATTINY2313 / ATMEGA328P

Tags: arduino-mega, attiny, atmega328, avr, isp

I have posted this on the Arduino forum also, but I give it more chance if posted here also.

I've been trying to use my Arduino Mega as an ISP for programming two different ATMEGA328P's and a ATINY2313, but I just don't succeed.

I am running the Arduino IDE (version 1.5.8 ) on windows 7. I've been using these http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Arduino-Mega-2560-as-Arduino-isp/ http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-ATtiny2313-Programming-Shield/ instructables for help. The circuit are built on a breadboard. On my Arduino Mega is use the pins reset: 53, MOSI: 51, MISO: 50, SCK: 52.

First I upload the arduino as ISP sketch on my Mega. There are LEDs on the programming, error and heartbeat outputs, the heardbeat is pounding. I then select the according board from the boards list (the ATINY2313 1MHz from the instructable for the ATTINY and either the Arduino UNO or the Arduino Duelimanove for the ATMEGA328P) and after that the programmer árduino as ISP'. When uploading the Blink sketch I get errors like:

avrdude: Yikes! Invalid device signature
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_disable(): protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x51
I have tried things like capacitors/resistors between the reset and the ground or between the reset and the +5V, but nothing different. I have searched for help on the internet and alot of people have problems with it, but no clear or working answers. I have been looking at the MegaISP guide form Arduino, but this is not very clear to me.

I have no idea where to start anymore. Does anybody have an idea what I can try or where to start searching for answers?

I appriciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Try a bigger capacitor. Also, putting it between reset and GND sound more logical to me. Looking at the schematic you can also put a jumper between 5V and RST. [similar error](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Arduino-Mega-2560-as-Arduino-isp/step3/Finally-uploading-the-programs-to-your-new-arduino/)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me dude :)

See this:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Bootloading-ATmega328-with-Arduino-Mega2560/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: You might want to cite the most interesting parts of your source/link.
In case the link might go dead.
Also, to avoid getting 10's of answers with only links. Which isn't manageable and you'll have to visit each link to check what the good/best answer is.
Read this for more information on single-line or link-only answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156941/one-line-answers